# Controle de concorrência em multi-thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, concorrência

Preciso desenvolver um Windows Service com C# que verifica uma tabela no banco de dados(Sql Server 2008). Nessa tabela tem os dados que eu preciso e um campo Status(`Ready,Processing, Processed, Error`).

O serviço irá pegar sempre o primeiro resultado com o Status `Ready`, e assim que pegar, ele irá atualizar o status para `Processing`.

Agora minha dúvida, qual a melhor forma de fazer o controle de concorrência disso, pois pretendo utilizar 4 threads simultâneas.

Como fazer para que as threads não peguem um valor repetido?

Comment: Porque você precisa de 4 threads simultâneas para consultar o status? Não pode consultar em apenas uma, e essa criar as novas threads para processar sua informação. O que vai fazer esse serviço?

Comment: Sim, estou pensando em fazer uma unica busca e adicionar em uma lista, e fazer um gerenciador dessa lista passando o ID e removendo da lista. Acho que dessa forma vai ficar mais performático.